# How configure code cell with in google colabs

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a problem using a notebook in Google Colab. It's related to the width of code cells; the width has been reduced, and I can't see what's written. This only happens on PCs; on a tablet, the full width of the cell is visible as usual. How can I adjust the width?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgCv.png)